# Find <style> tag by id or attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to dynamically remove or disable a `<style>` tag

that looks like this

```
<style type="text/css" id="cssx/portal/simple-sidebar.css" designtr="cssx/portal/simple-sidebar.css">


#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

</style>
```

if I have the id or my own defined designtr property, I can't seem to disable or remove it like so:

```
        var id = 'x';
        var designtr = 'x';

        document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;  //doesn't work, throws an error saying element is null
        $('style[designtr="' + designtr + '"]').remove();   //doesn't work, although strangely no error thrown
```

I read somewhere that even with HTML5 style tags can't have a valid id attribute.

All I want to do is either remove or disable a style tag, given some unique id that I have in hand.

Comment: Where is that script in the page? It looks like it should work, but if the script is before the style tag in the document, it won't have been processed by the browser, so you can't access it. If you don't want to move the script, you can wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){ your code });`

Comment: Have you tried with a more *orthodox* `id`?

Comment: eh, I was hoping the slashes wouldn't make a difference, but I will test that theory also thanks

Answer (score 4):

Works like a charm:

```js
document.getElementById('remove').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('styl').remove();
};
```

```html
<div>Some Div Content</div>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
<style id="styl">div{background-color: red}</style>
```

Comment: my style tags are in the body if that makes any difference

Comment: the style element in this example is also in the body

Comment: yeah I see that yours works, upvoted, but it's not working for me, not sure what the deal is

Comment: Then you should create a MCVE

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id$=css]").remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" id="cssx/portal/simple-sidebar.css" designtr="cssx/portal/simple-sidebar.css">


#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    color:blue;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

</style>
<div id="side-wrapper">abc</div>
```

Comment: @AlexMills See also http://superuser.com/questions/447269/is-there-any-way-to-view-a-webpage-without-styles-in-chrome